# Is there any alternative of swing?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any alternative of swing? 
I need a high performance GUI toolkit to create desktop application on linux (Ubuntu). I've been creating swing application for 2 years, therefore I want use java.

Comment: Java 8 + JavaFX. Still new, but active. Much better, effects, properties (=model of data with listeners).

Comment: *"I've been creating swing application for 2 years, therefore I want use java."* - Not necessarily.  You could have been hating Java the whole time :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Java FX. It will give you better performance than java Swing. [Java FX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html)

Comment: JavaFX is designed for WEB as opposed to Desktop Applications

Comment: Here is the definition for JavaFx : "JavaFX is a software platform for creating and delivering rich internet applications (RIAs) that can run across a wide variety of devices. JavaFX is intended to replace Swing as the standard GUI library for Java SE, but both will be included for the foreseeable future"

Comment: I have seen this statement and to me it does not really make sense ... Oracle says that JavaFX is for "creating and delivering rich internet applications" and its a intended to replace Swing.. Well fair enough but swing was never designed to deliver rich internet applications ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there's a number of other UI toolkits available - AWT, SWT, JavaFX, QT to name a few.

I'd primarily recommend JavaFX as the new UI toolkit (it's now part of Java8 and is still under heavy development) or perhaps SWT if you want the "native" feel (since it uses native OS components.) QT does this as well of course, but it requires bindings and is generally more of a faff - so its use is relatively rare in Java land.

On the other sided of things, I'd recommend staying away from AWT (it's the old, original Java GUI framework that lacks many common components in other UI toolkits, and is not really supported any more.)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at JavaFX it's now part of the JRE/JDK for Java 8.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use SWT as an alternative.

https://www.eclipse.org/swt/

Comment: I am not sure that SWT perfomance better than swing